# Content Length header is changing after posting xml (HTTP POST using libcurl)

Tags: xml, curl, http-headers, http-post, libcurl

I am using libcurl to send xml data to server.I am using `readfunction` method to Post data.But after posting headers, `content-length` header is changing to -1. and I get the error message from libcurl as : -
`HTTP error before end of send, stop sending`

```
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 249

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><STBSCANMANUALINFO><FREQUENCY>305944</FREQUENCY>       <SYMBOLRATE>6899</SYMBOLRATE><MODULATION> MOD_64QAM</MODULATION><STATUS> LOCKED</STATUS><QUALITY>100</QUALITY><BER>0</BER><RFLEVEL>40</RFLEVEL></STBSCANMANUALINFO>
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length: -1
Expect: 100-continue
```

I am not getting where am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPOSTFIELDSIZE) to explicitly set the `POST` size as illustrated by this [official sample code](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/post-callback.html):

```
/* Set the expected POST size. If you want to POST large amounts of data,
   consider CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE */ 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, pooh.sizeleft);
```